# Pivot Table contains extra rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following query to generate a table of Financial Aid awards for a student. We want to do a Pivot since we want to show aid for multiple semesters at the same time.

```
select pt.award as Award, pt.[1] as Fall, pt.[2] as Spring, pt.[3] as Summer            
--into #awardTemp
  from (select fa.Description as award, fa.OriginalAmount, fa.TextTerm,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fa.description 
            order by fa.textterm) AS M
      from CAMS_Enterprise.dbo.cams_FinancialAward_view as fa
        where fa.Code1ID = 0
      and fa.StudentAccepted is null
      and fa.studentuid = @studentuid) as AT
  pivot (max(at.originalamount) for at.m in ([1],[2],[3])) as pt
```

Instead of listing the amounts per semester on the same line, we get results that look like below. Even though the description titles are the same, each semester of awards gets its own row. Anyone know where the problem is coming from?

```
Academic Scholarship                5000.00 NULL    NULL
Academic Scholarship                NULL    5000.00 NULL
Federal Subsidized Stafford Loan    1750.00 NULL    NULL
Federal Subsidized Stafford Loan    NULL    1750.00 NULL
Federal Unsubsidized Stafford Loan  1000.00 NULL    NULL
Federal Unsubsidized Stafford Loan  NULL    1000.00 NULL
```

Comment: What happens when you just run select pt.*? That'll show why you're getting duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your data from the table before the `pivot`, I am going to guess that it is due to the inclusion of `fa.TextTerm` in the query.

This is giving a distinct value of `TextTerm` that is causing multiple rows.

This seems to be the obvious reason for the problem because you are not using that column in the final `SELECT` list. I would suggest altering your query to:

```
select pt.award as Award, pt.[1] as Fall, pt.[2] as Spring, pt.[3] as Summer            
--into #awardTemp
from 
(
    select fa.Description as award, 
        fa.OriginalAmount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fa.description order by fa.textterm) AS M
    from CAMS_Enterprise.dbo.cams_FinancialAward_view as fa
    where fa.Code1ID = 0
      and fa.StudentAccepted is null
      and fa.studentuid = @studentuid
) as AT
pivot 
(
    max(at.originalamount) 
    for at.m in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pt
```

Comment: GREAT! That works exactly how I need it to. Thanks, I've been looking at this for about 2 hours and it was driving me nuts.